# Обновляемый текстовый файл с котировками тиккеров

Tags: python, данные

передо мной стоит задача сделать текстовый файл, который должен содержать: название тиккера, его цену, % изменения.
Данные решил брать с платформы Tradernet: https://tradernet.ru/tradernet-api/quotes-get
Посоветовавшись, реализовать сие мероприятие решил на Python, но навыки написания кода отсутствуют(всё понимаю, но с нуля не идет).
Буду признателен за любые строки кода, которые помогут или же ссылки на схожие решенные кейсы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, советую взять примеры по проще. Допустим - брать какой-то сайт который передаёт `json`, и этот `json` писать в документ. По поводу `json`: сначала ставите библиотеку `requests` `(pip install requests)`, и сам код -

```
import requests
request = requests.get("Сайт с реквестом json")
print(кequest.json())
```

Он вам выведет данные которые идут в списке `json`.
Потом же лучше уже работать с `api`, но это не ко мне.
Даю только то что знаю о этом)